# I think I am exceeding available memory for this process. Can someone take a look and verify?

Tags: c, file, memory, memory-management

When I do not open the file(180mb) I get no error, but when I open the file I get a Segmentation fault 11. I am fairly certain that I am exceeding memory for the process. Anyone have any tips?

I have changed parameters. So if NUM_TRAIN = 10 instead of 60000, I do not get a segmentation fault. When NUM_TRAIN = 60000, but I do not open the file, I also do not get a segmentation fault. When NUM_TRAIN = 60000 and I open the file, I get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_TRAIN 60000
#define IMAGE_SIZE 784
#define TRAIN_IMAGES "mnist_train.csv"
int main()
{
  int arr[NUM_TRAIN][IMAGE_SIZE];
  int arr2[NUM_TRAIN];
  FILE* fTrain = fopen(TRAIN_IMAGES, "r");
  return 0;
}
```

I do not expect to get a segmentation fault but I am, specifically a Segmentation fault 11

Comment: Allocate your arrays on the heap instead of the stack, by using malloc.  Or, define the array outside of main(), which will put it into the global memory area.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating these arrays on the stack.  Unlike the heap, this has a strictly limited capacity and cannot be expanded.  Limits between `1-8MB` are common.

Instead allocate on the heap:

```
int **arr = malloc(sizeof(int *) * NUM_TRAIN);

for (int i=0; i < NUM_TRAIN; ++i)
{
   arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * IMAGE_SIZE);
}
```

A two-dimensional array of `int` is in fact an array of pointers to arrays of `int`.

You ought to check for errors during the caller to `malloc()` - omitted here.

Comment: Do not use `int **arr` for simple two-dimensional arrays. It wastes space and time. Use `int (*arr)[IMAGE_SIZE];` and `arr = malloc(NUM_TRAIN * sizeof *arr);`.

Comment: A two-dimensional array of `int` is not in fact an array of pointers to arrays of `int`.

Comment: It's been ages since I did C... why isn't he getting the seg fault when he doesn't open the file? (Maybe the compiler optimizes the allocation away because 'not opening the file' means he commented the line out?)

Comment: @EricJ.: Most likely OP is not showing the full code and, when the file is not opened, OP is also omitting the code that would use the arrays, or the compiler is able to deduce they are not used, and therefore the compiler optimizes away the creation of the arrays. Then stack is not used, so there is no segmentation fault.

Comment: Allocating the array causes the stack pointer to exceeds the stack limit; the next thing that is pushed there (for instance, a function call) blows it up.   Could equally be the next variable that is spilled.

Comment: @marko: The question Eric J. asked is not why the stack overflows but rather why there is a difference between whether it does or does not overflow as a consequence of whether the file is opened or not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, I posted the entirety of the code. This was in a test file and the exact behavior I discussed is what took place.

Comment: @JohnMancini: Then a proper question and answer requires posting the complete version information of the compiler and other tools and the exact commands used to compile and run, possibly along with enough information to reproduce the input file sufficiently to reproduce the crash. As stated, no good compiler would exhibit the difference in behavior reported; it would either keep the arrays (if optimization were disabled) and crash regardless of whether the file were opened or not or remove the arrays (if optimization were enabled) and not crash regardless.

Comment: @EricPostpischil none of the declarations of the arrays write to the stack (don't pay for initialisation when it's not needed)- but calling `fopen()` pushes a stack frame to it.  Presumably by 'not opening the file', the OP is commenting out this line.

Comment: @JohnMancini: One other possibility is the crash is actually caused by `fTrain` and/or the stack frame to call `fopen` being located below the arrays and used if the file is opened but not if the file is not opened, and hence there would be a difference. But that is still a sign of a compiler shortcoming, as it requires space for the arrays to be allocated even though they are not used but also for that space not to be touched so as to avoid causing a crash.

Comment: The push of a stack frame on function call would happen first in that case.   No guarantees that `fTrain` is ever written to the stack at all - could easy remain in a register.  The stack frame will always be below the current frame.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue. Basically I was allocating way too much static memory with the arrays, so I changed the code to dynamically allocate the memory to the heap. Code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_TRAIN 60000
#define IMAGE_SIZE 784
#define TRAIN_IMAGES "mnist_train.csv"
int main()
{
  int** arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*NUM_TRAIN);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRAIN; i++)
    arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*IMAGE_SIZE);
  int* arr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_TRAIN);
  FILE* fTrain = fopen(TRAIN_IMAGES, "r");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `int **arr` for simple two-dimensional arrays. It wastes space and time. Use `int (*arr)[IMAGE_SIZE];` and `arr = malloc(NUM_TRAIN * sizeof *arr);`.

Comment: Re “I was allocating way too much static memory”: Inside a function, int arr[NUM_TRAIN][IMAGE_SIZE]; does not allocate static memory; it allocates automatic memory, which is most often implemented with a stack.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can you explain why that is more space and time efficient?

Comment: @JohnMancini, because Eric's version requires only one `malloc()` call (and later, only one `free()`), as opposed to `NUM_TRAIN + 1` of them, and it reserves space only for the needed `int`s, not for an additional `NUM_TRAIN` pointers.  Also, one less indirection is required for access, and all the `int`s are certain to be in a single, contiguous block, which may contribute to better cache locality.  All in all, Eric's version is *much* better.

Comment: Not to mention that the two approaches produce objects that, although they can be accessed with the same indexing syntax, are in fact of importantly different type.  The difference becomes apparent when you pass them as function arguments, among other places.